# How to save photos to phones library/album?

Tags: ios

In my app i am having one image view which is containing the profile picture of a user and on this image view i am having one another image view which contains the picture of product. So the is basically try product yourself kind a app.I am able to do all this stuff but finally when the user is done with trying that product and if he want to save that final picture containing applied product, he will click the save button.I don't know how to save this final picture which will contain images from two image views. Please guide me through this..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will serve your purpose. It is for saving the image in library.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void  *contextInfo);
```

Example:

```
UIImage* imageToSave = [imageView image]; // alternatively, imageView.image

// Save it to the camera roll / saved photo album
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: hey but will it save the combined final image from both imageviews,as i mentioned.

Comment: I expect 2nd image is a subview of 1st image and then you can save 1st image directly in library